# What am I not getting about Go sql query with variables?

Tags: postgresql, variables, go

I'm brand new to Go, and I've started working on some postgres queries, and I'm having very little luck.

I have a package that's just going to have some database queries in it.  Here's my code.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Querying data")
    myqueries.SelectAll("mytable")

}
```

**myqueries.go**

```
package myqueries

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
)

func SelectAll (table string) {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres","user=postgres dbname=mydb sslmode=disable")

        if err != nil {
                 fmt.Println(err)
        }

        defer db.Close()

        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM $1", table)

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        } else {

                PrintRows(rows)
        }

}

func PrintRows(rows *sql.Rows) {
    for rows.Next() {
        var firstname string
        var lastname string

        err := rows.Scan(&firstname, &lastname)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("first name | last name")

        fmt.Println("%v | %v\n", firstname, lastname)

    }
}
```

The error I get is `pq: syntax error at or near "$1"`

which is from **myqueries.go** file in the `db.Query`.

I've tried several variations of this, but nothing has worked yet.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are using https://github.com/lib/pq based on the error message and it's [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq) say that

> pq uses the Postgres-native ordinal markers, as shown above

I've never known a database engine that allows the parameterized values in anything other than values. I think you are going to have to resort to string concatenation. I don't have a Go compiler available to me right now, but try something like this. Because you are inserting the table name by concatination, you need it sanitized. [`pq.QuoteIdentifier`](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#QuoteIdentifier) should be able to help with that.

```
func SelectAll (table string) {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres","user=postgres dbname=mydb sslmode=disable")

        if err != nil {
                 fmt.Println(err)
        }

        defer db.Close()

        table = pq.QuoteIdentifier(table)
        rows, err := db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM %v", table))

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        } else {

                PrintRows(rows)
        }

}
```

EDIT: Thanks to hobbs to pointing out `pq.QuoteIdentifier`

Comment: [pq.QuoteIdentifier](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#QuoteIdentifier) should be what's needed to finish the job.

Comment: Thank you both, that's exactly what I needed.  And to anyone who swings by that is new to go, to use pq, just ```go get github.com/lib/pq```, then use ```import "github.com/lib/pq"``` at the top of your file.